# return object of type that is passed to class

Tags: c#, generics, types

Let's say I have the class

```
class SomeClass<T>
{

    public static void someMethod(T param1) // this gives an error
                                            // I have to do something like (var param1)

    {
        // ...
        // ...
    }
}
```

How could require param1 to be of type T so that I can call the method as:

```
SomeOtherClass object1 = new SomeOtherClass();
SomeClass<SomeOtherClass>.someMethod(object1);
```

Comment: How can `(var param1)` on a method sig work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class SomeClass<T>
{

    public static void someMethod<T>(T myobject)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a generic method instead.

```
public static void SomeMethod<T>(T param1) ...
```

Comment: and if you want to add restriction then add where T : SomeOtherClass

Answer (score 0):

I do not know C# very well, but I think you would want to apply the generic type definition to the method rather than the class.

```
public static void someMethod<T>(T param1)
{
    //not sure where <T> definition goes in signature...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get? It is probably related to something other than the method signature. This works fine for me:

```
class SomeClass<T>
{
    public static void someMethod(T param1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param1);
    }
}
```

...

```
SomeClass<int>.someMethod(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tono your code is right. According to what Brandon says (and dislike some other pretend), you don't have to make your method generic since **the whole class** it belongs to is already generic... except if you'd wish to have a type parameter for this method different from the class' type parameter :

```
class SomeClass<T>
{
     public static void someMethod<U>(U myobject)
     {
     }
}
```

Which, obviously, is absolutely not what you want.

By the way in danyolgiax' answer, the compiler will raise an error because of the conflict name between the class' type parameter named T and the method's type parameter also (badly) named T.

It is sure your error comes from somewhere else. Why not mentioning the exact error message you get ? This will be half way to the solution. :-)